# How to use template from both current file and the file that is imported as mixins in vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

```
var Foo = new Vue({
  template: `<div><p>this is in Foo</p></div>`
})

var Bar = new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mixins: [Foo],
  created () {
    console.log(Foo)
  },
  template: `<div>` + Foo.$options.template + `<p>others</p></div>`
})
```

output:

`// this is in Foo

// others`

It is in https://jsfiddle.net/once_ss/eywraw8t/424968
The code shows that you can keep the template from Foo `this is in Foo` and the template from Bar `others`.
But I can't find a way to do the same thing in vue-cli.
In my trials, you can just keep the template from Foo (if no `<tempalte></template>` in Bar) OR the template from Bar (if there is `<tempalte>...</template>` in Bar).

I think it should be possible in vue-cli, but could someone tell me how?

Comment: what's your use case? it seems like you want to use components

Comment: I want to make page template.  For example, there are many pages which all have a list part and a detail part, and they all have 'insert new', 'delete row', 'modify row' functions, only the data is different.   If I have template, it can be easier to write each page(all are inherited from template).

Comment: In this case, I need functions/methods and UI which can be overwrite as need.  Extends/mixins can solve the problem in parts except UI, but the problem of UI remains.

Comment: you could create and use component with same UI and with shared mixins

Comment: It is the point, if template cannot be inherited, it will be too much duplicate code and hard to control.

Comment: it's not duplicate you create one component with the same UI and change only the data